# How to keep label after using mutate?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have a very basic question. Let's look at head(mtcars), we see

```
                       mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
    Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
    Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
    Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
    Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
    Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Suppose I do

```
new_dataset<-mutate(mtcars, displ_l = disp / 61.0237)
```

we obtain

```
       mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  displ_l
    1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2.621932
    2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2.621932
    3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.769804
    4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 4.227866
    5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.899347
    6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 3.687092
```

Is there an easy way for me to retain the row labels, i.e. Mazda RX4, Mazda RX4 Wag, etc. in my mutated dataset?

Comment: the `sticky` package can retain attributes, but I usually just save the labels, mutate, then re-add the labels

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue here isn't `mutate`, per se, it is that the tidyverse does everything in tibbles, not data frames, and one difference they have imposed is that tibbles never have row names. So in general, if you have row names, and want to use tidyverse tools, you will always need to do `rownames_to_column()` up front.

Comment: @joran The issue seems to be mutate here: "When applied to a data frame, row names are silently dropped. " from `?mutate`. The code OP posted returns an object of class `data.frame`.

Comment: @markus You're right, I was being a little sloppy. A more accurate version of my comment would be something along the lines of, "since the tidyverse often relies on tibbles, rather than data frames, you can't assume that row names will be preserved, so you have to be defensive about it".

Comment: Thanks everyone

@RAB How exactly do you save the labels and re-add them? Which function do you use?

Comment: you can use `labs <- Hmisc::label(data)`, then afterwards `as.list(labs[match(names(new_data), names(labs))])`. Thats how I do it in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
library(tibble)
new_dataset <- mtcars %>%
rownames_to_column('Car_brand'#Name of new column here <-
) %>%
mutate(
 displ_l = disp / 61.0237
)
```